# What is the term for a text box where users can type anything they want

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-request, terminology

What is the term for a text box on a webpage/form/etc. like a comment box where a user can type anything they want?  The term I'm thinking of doesn't sound right.

I want to call this a free form text box but that doesn't sound correct.

Thanks for any terms you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

"Free-form" is exactly what I would call it.  Then I would be using it in a technical conversation.

There's no non-technical equivalent.  If you want to not use "free-form" you probably have to spell out what you mean in a longer phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the simple term **"text box"**? That seems to be the most appropriate term and is quite likely to be understood by everyone.

I don't think "free-form" is a commonly used term. On its own, it sounds strange to me:

> Please enter your comment in the free-form below.

You can also use **"text field"**, which sounds more natural than "free-form", at least to me. But what is *natural* really? Who is your audience?

"Free-form text box" or "free-form text field" would be fine, but they just add more words that are not necessary to say what you are referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In technical terms, we use “**text area**”. It’s commonly used to enter comments and suggestions.

Definition of **Text Area**:

> A text area is a large box that allows you to enter multiple lines of text.

---

According to [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp):

> A text area is often used in a form, to collect user inputs like **comments** or reviews.